# Why can you see a seam in my model from far away?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I have a mirrored object, which would obviously have a seam in the middle. However I'm sure the way I created the texture, it would be hard to tell.

[image]

But when seen from far away, it's extremely visible, how come?

Comment: Suspect mip-mapping and UV textures with insufficient borders.  See if it goes away when you use closest filtering.

Comment: What's closest filtering?

Comment: On your image texture node.  Default is "linear".

Comment: I think it works. Tysm!

Comment: Closest filtering is more diagnostic than a good solution.  A good solution is to use texture images with significant margins-- ie, color outside of the lines.

Comment: Oh ok. Though I'm confused why. Does it use a higher margin outside of its UV island the further you are from it?

Comment: Yes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering

Comment: Oh I found another good resource: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding

Comment: Dammit @Nathan, you really seem to know everything :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Except how to make good art :(

Comment: @Nathan *"Nah, art is overrated, good design is way harder"* Massimo Vignelli, probably :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nathan and me:

You can change the filtering method on your image node to "closest."

However, "Closest filtering is more diagnostic than a good solution." It is better to "use texture images with significant margins."

This is needed since objects use texture space outside of their UV maps when seen from far away explained by http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding.

Nathan provides the resource en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering

Comment: Sorry, I should have made those comments an answer, but it was one of those situations where I started out just needing to know a little more info.